# Javascript alternative to the HTML "required" function?

Tags: javascript, html

So the `required` function on a html form works correctly in major web browsers, but it doesn't work with safari or on mobile devices. Is there a way to make users input text before proceeding using Javascript?

Here's my javascript code (making limited characters);

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } else {
        limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
    }
}
</script>
```

and here's the html form input I wish to apply the required function too;

```
<p id="username-field">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>        
    <input name="username" type="text" id="username" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.limitedtextfield,this.form.countdown,15);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.limitedtextfield,this.form.countdown,15);" maxlength="15">        
    <a href="https://minecraft.net/retrievename">Forgot username?</a>
</p>
<p id="password-field">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input tabindex="2" type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.limitedtextfield,this.form.countdown,15);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.limitedtextfield,this.form.countdown,15);" maxlength="15" required />
    <a href="https://minecraft.net/resetpassword">Forgot password?</a>
</p>
<p id="remember-field">
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" value="true"  />
    <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
</p>
<p>Clicking Submit will direct you to a page where you can see the information given.</p>

<!--<a href="#" target=""><p>Don't want to enter anything at all? Click this line to view a GIF of the procedure!</p></a>-->

<p class="middle">Or</p>
<a href="done.php"><p>Visit the page containing already made fake-accounts displaying login information.</p></a>
<p id="signin-field">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />
</p>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about attaching .submit() eventHandler to the form, where you can validate anything you want? Simply, if something not okay, you can just output some message and use *return false;* , to prevent default form action.

Comment: please show your entire form code so we can suggest an appropriate fix.

Comment: added full `<form>` code.

Answer (score 0):

Well html5 attribute 'min' works in safari:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp

You could try that.